# merge two datasets to find a mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, mean

I have two similar looking tables:
df1:

```
country    type       mean     count     last_checked_date
Brazil     Weather     x       2         2022-02-13    
Brazil     Corona      y       3         2022-02-13
China      Corona      z       1         2022-02-13
China      Fruits      s       2         2022-02-13
```

df2

```
country    type       mean     count     last_checked_date
Ghana      Weather     a       2         2022-02-13    
Brazil     Corona      b       5          2022-02-13
China      Corona      c       1         2022-02-13
Germany    Fruits      d       2         2022-02-13
```

I want to join df2 with df1 such that no combination of country, type is lost. For each combination of country and type, I want to calculate a mean value with this formula:

```
df find_new_values(old_mean, new_mean, old_count, new_count):
    mean = (old_mean + new_mean)/(old_count+new_count)
    count = old_count+new_count
    return mean, count
```

For example, in df2, China, Corona is present in df1 as well so the mean would be (c+z)/(1+1)

However, Ghana, Weather is present in df2 but not in df1 so in this case, I want to simply add a row to df1 as it is without the formula calculation.

How can I achieve this? What's the correct join/merge type to use here?

Answer (score 0):

We may consider the problem this way, we combine them into one table,

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

then use `groupby` to apply aggregations on each group of the rows that share the same `country` and `type`.

```
df.groupby(['country', 'type']).agg({'mean': 'mean', 'count': 'sum'})
```

For country-type combination that only occur once in one of the dataframe, the corresponding group will only discover one row and the aggregation functions won't change anything.

You may add `'last_checked_date': 'last'` to the list of `agg` if needed.

Comment: instead of creating a new df, isnt it possible to just add rows from df2 to df1?

Comment: You mean to manually add - it's possible. To discover which combo of country-type exists in df2 but not df1, you may set both 'country' and 'type' as the indices of both dataframes, then use df2.index.difference(df1.index) to find them. after that you can use those discovered indices to index the corresponding rows from df2 and append them to df1.